# How can I avoid receiving Flipboard emails/notifications

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Nougat.

I keep on receiving emails/notifications from Flipboard. They don't use my old registration email address but MY GOOGLE ACCOUNT ADDRESS.

I checked in settings but I didn't find nothing that I can do. Hence,the only way to avoid receiving emails is to delete the account? Or,are there other ways?

Update:

I DIDN'T CREATE A FLIPBOARD ACCOUNT WITH GOOGLE ACCOUNT EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD.
Now I deleted this account but it's still working.Need I to wait?  
Can,please,someone suggest to me if it's better to delete the old account too?and change,I know it's not so easy, email address and password of my Google account?
The question,now,is who has made the "Google account"and where have they found my Google credentials?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To stop receiving emails from Flipboard, simply unsubscribe from their email list. You can usually find an unsubscribe link at the bottom of the email.

If you can't find the link, use [this](https://flemail.flipboard.com/account/unsubscribe?) page to unsubscribe.

To stop receiving notifications from the app, go to your phone settings -> application Manager -> Flipboard -> notifications, and switch "allow notifications" to "off"

Comment: @A bochur,thank you for your answer.Can you,please,read my update.BTW,I checked "notification" are blocked.Thank you

Comment: @ubu16 if you didn't create the account, then which account did you delete?

Comment: @ubu16 next time you get a notification from Flipboard, long press on it and disable notifications, if that doesn't help, all i can say that this is very strange.

Comment: @A bochur,I have a Flipboard account,that has nothing to do with Google.One day I received an email on gmail from Flipboard on my smartphone and I realized that I had many emails from Flipboard.Therefore I checked on Flipboard site I had 2 account.Now I deleted the account with email address and password of my Google account.I'm thinking to delete the old account too and change my Google account email address and password but it is not so easy.The question is who has created the"Google account"and where have they found my Google email address and password?

Comment: @ubu16 very possible that it got your info from your phone. I'd suggest that next time, simply unsubscribe and you'll be fine

Comment: @A bochur,as I said,I already have deleted the "Google"account.Do you suggest to me to delete the old account too?and change my Google account credentials?Thank you

Comment: @ubu16 i don't see a need for that.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately clicking the unsubscribe button just results in "Error". Horrible company.